# jqueryui tabs, each tab has datatable. automatically filter each table

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, datatables

I have a page with jqueryui tabbed layout.
the first tab I show entire table (unfiltered).
in each of the next tabs, I want to show same table, but filtered on first column.
what I currently have, is just the same data shown x times..
when I say "filter:true", that provides a search box..... I don't think I want that, I just want the data automatically filtered...
data[0] contains my table data, data[1] contains my list of filters.

```
$.each(data[1], function(key, work_center){
    $('#table_'+ iii).DataTable({
        data: data[0],
        columns: [
            {title: 'WorkCenter', data: 'workCenter', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Shop Order', data: 'shopOrder', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Item', data: 'soItem', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'RawMatl', data: 'rawMateral', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'CreatedDate', data: 'soCreated', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'DueDate', data: 'soDueDate', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'QtyRqd', data: 'QtyReqrd', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'QtyFin', data: 'QtyFinished', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Comment', data: 'soComment', width: '25%'},
            {title: 'User', data: 'soUser', width: '10%'}
        ],
        filter: false,
        lengthChange: false,
        paging: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        retrieve: false,
        destroy: true,
        info: false
    });
    iii++;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is how I got it working...

```
$.each(data[1], function(key, work_center){
    **var wc_filter = '' + work_center;**
    **table =** $('#table_'+ iii).DataTable({
        data: data[0],
        columns: [
            { title: 'WorkCenter', data: 'workCenter', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Shop Order', data: 'shopOrder', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Item', data: 'soItem', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'RawMatl', data: 'rawMateral', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'CreatedDate', data: 'soCreated', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'DueDate', data: 'soDueDate', width: '10%'},
            {title: 'QtyRqd', data: 'QtyReqrd', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'QtyFin', data: 'QtyFinished', width: '5%'},
            {title: 'Comment', data: 'soComment', width: '25%'},
            {title: 'User', data: 'soUser', width: '10%'}
        ],
        filter:  **true**,
        lengthChange: false,
        paging: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        retrieve: false,
        destroy: true,
        info: false
    });
    **table
        .columns(0)
        .search( wc_filter )
        .draw();**
    iii++;
});
```

I pushed my datatable config to a variable.
then I modified the variable with the
.columns(0).search( wc_filter).draw() elements.

I had also change the filter element from false to true (although I would rather not have the search box appear?)